# How to print the result of a Phalcon query result?

Tags: php, phalcon

There is a `Phalcon` query :

```
     function lireParCritere($critere) {

        $sSQL = "
                SELECT c.salle_code,c.salle_lib,c.salle_comment 
                FROM salle as c WHERE 1 = 1 ";

        if(isset($critere["salle_code"]) && $critere["salle_code"] != "") {
            $sSQL .= "AND c.salle_code = ' " . $critere["salle_code"] . "' ";    
        }

        $query = new Query($sSQL,$this->getDI());

        $ret = $query->execute();

        return $ret;

    }
```

How to print the result of this `query` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does the function return? What format do you want it in?

Comment: what I did so far is knowing its type as an object ! Now I want to know how is its form ? Is it an object of array or something else ?

Comment: To find out what type it is, use `echo gettype(lireParCritere("xxx"));` or `$r=lireParCritere("xyz"); echo print_r($r,true).PHP_EOL;`. The first will tell you the type, the second will tell you the data that it contains. From there, write your code accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query` uses [PHQL](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html), not SQL.

```
public function lireParCritere($critere)
{
    $model = '\Namespaced\Path\To\Salle';

    $sSQL = "
            SELECT c.salle_code,c.salle_lib,c.salle_comment 
            FROM $model as c WHERE 1 = 1 ";

    if(isset($critere["salle_code"]) && $critere["salle_code"] != "") {
        $sSQL .= "AND c.salle_code = ' " . $critere["salle_code"] . "' ";    
    }

    $query = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query($sSQL, $this->getDI());

    $ret = $query->execute();

    return $ret;

}

public function test()
{
    foreach ($this->lireParCritere([]) as $row) {
        /** @var \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row $row */
        assert($row->salle_code === $row->readAttribute('salle_code'));

    }
}
```